# Writing the classical Mean Squared Error (MSE) as an integral

Tags: signal-processing, parameter-estimation

Consider some quantity $x$ that is to be estimated using the data vector $y$.
In [Stephen M Kay's book on Estimation Theory](https://www.pearson.com/en-us/subject-catalog/p/fundamentals-of-statistical-processing-estimation-theory-volume-1/P200000009271/9780133457117), the classical MSE is written as (eq. 10.3, p. 311)
\begin{equation}
\int(x-\hat x)^2 \ p(y\vert x)\ dy
\end{equation}
whereas the Bayesian MSE is (eq.10.2)
\begin{equation}
\iint(x-\hat x)^2 \ p(y, x)\ dy\ dx
\end{equation}

1. Now I can make sense of the Bayesian MSE, but where does the integral for the classical MSE come from? Or what is a natural interpretation for it?
2. As a follow-up question, which of these would $\mathbb{E}\left[(x-\hat x)^2\right]$ refer to? Does it depend on the context?

Comment: The idea is that you have a family of probability distributions (here they are all assumed to be continuous.) And you assume that it is possible to identify which distribution with just knowledge of the vector $x$. So $p(y\mid x)$ denotes the density of some random variable, and the integral comes from the law of the unconscious statistician.

Comment: @AndrewZhang so you are saying that distribution of the data is parameterized by just $x$. AFAIK the LOTUS on the other hand is for finding moments of f(x) where x is the random variable. but the integral is over the data vector $y$, which is what had me confused

Comment: Ok using the LOTUS I can see that $\int (x-\hat x)^2 p(x)dx = \iint (x-\hat x)^2 p(x|y)p(y)dydx = \iint (x-\hat x)^2 p(y|x)p(x)dydx$ 
Thereafter we can assume that p(x) is a dirac delta fn (since we are in the classical estimation setting)? If so, that does answer my question.

Comment: I think it will help to use different letters. It's more common to have the parameter called $\theta$, and we have some estimator $\hat \theta(X_1,\dots,X_N)$, where let's say the $X_N$ are i.i.d, with density $f$. Then $$ E(\hat \theta-\theta)^2 = \int (\hat \theta(x_1,\dots,x_n) - \theta)^2 f(x_1)\cdots f(x_n)\,dx_1\dots dx_n$$. Does that help?

Comment: Oh yeah it does, thanks! Especially now that i see that the conditional density I was using ($p(y|x)$) is is to be interpreted as the parameterized function $p(y;x)$ instead, which was your first comment too.